# Attach last column of DataFrame to another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.4

I have a large csv file which I convert to a `pandas.DataFrame`. Afterwards, I split this dataframe into a few smaller ones, process them and convert each of them back to a csv file.

In the processing step, I need to attach the last column of the original dataframe to the smaller data frames. I tried to do it with `df.iloc[:,-1]` and `df.ix[:,-1]`.

When I do this:

```
        rating_column = df.iloc[:,-1]    #get last column from original dataframe
        print(rating_column)
```

I get the right result:

```
        timestamp
        2015-07-22 21:40:00    passed
        2015-07-22 21:50:00    passed
        2015-07-22 22:00:00    passed
        2015-07-22 22:10:00    failed
```

But when I add that column to the smaller dataframe with `small_df['rating'] = rating_column`, the small_df only contains NaN for that column:

```
        timestamp              average       rating
        2015-07-22 21:40:00         73       NaN
        2015-07-22 21:50:00         74       NaN
        2015-07-22 22:00:00         73       NaN
        2015-07-22 22:10:00        NaN       NaN
```

How can I attach this column to the `small_df` without getting NaN values?

This is the code for reading the csv file:

```
import pandas as pd
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, 
                parse_dates=True, 
                index_col=0, 
                sep=';',
                header=None, 
                skipinitialspace=True, 
                low_memory=False, 
                names=range(0,amount_of_columns))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the index values don't match so it will try to align using the indices. Try adding the column as plain np array values:

```
small_df['rating'] = rating_column.values
```

However, the above assumes that the order matches across all your csv's, if you have some identifier columns then it's better to join/merge using this so that the row values are aligned.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works like a charm! I was stuck on it for about 2 hours

Comment: Was planning to do that, but I have to wait for a few minutes before it is possible to accept an answer